# RESTfull service - what type is getting information with filters?

Tags: php, rest

I'm writing a RESTfull service, using PHP, and I wanted to know which method type is the most correct for getting table's data, with filters?

I'm trying to follow this spec:
http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

GET seems to be the most obvious, but if I have filter parameters, built like this:

`{filter: [{'field': 'name', 'type': 'contains', 'value': 'ABC'},{....},{...}}`

Which I can easily send with POST, as a JSON payload.

So do I use GET, POST, or other?

Comment: By the most strict definition of REST I would say you should use GET, but there is nothing stopping you from sending form data the body of a GET request or expecting form data in a GET request for that matter

Comment: Do you mean send it as a payload? I didn't think it is possible.. (Not URL) If URL, then how do I parse this `filter` object?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should use GET method for getting table's data.

The HTTP GET method is used to retrieve (or read) a representation of a resource.

```
Examples:
GET http://www.example.com/customers/12345
GET http://www.example.com/customers/12345/orders
GET http://www.example.com/buckets/sample
```

According to the design of the HTTP specification, GET (along with HEAD) requests are used only to
read data and not change it. Therefore, when used this way, they are considered safe. That is, they can
be called without risk of data modification or corruption—calling it once has the same effect as callingit 10 times, or none at all. Additionally, GET (and HEAD) is idempotent, which means that making
multiple identical requests ends up having the same result as a single request.

Note : Do not expose unsafe operations via GET—it should never modify any resources on the server.

Comment: Yeah, I understand why and where to use GET, but for my specific case, how can I send it with GET? the payload is Array of objects of several parameters

Comment: GET ---
GET is the simplest type of HTTP request method; the one that browsers use each time you click a link or type a URL into the address bar. It instructs the server to transmit the data identified by the URL to the client. Data should never be modified on the server side as a result of a GET request. In this sense, a GET request is read-only, but of course, once the client receives the data, it is free to do any operation with it on its own side - for instance, format it for display.

Comment: I understand. But how can I parse my structured data into a string I could use later? as a rule?